# How to prepend '(' to a string

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a column with 4 numbers, for example 1234. I need (1234) // between brackets

```sql
update table set column=overlay(column placing ')' from 5) where table_ID=1
```

I get 1234) --> missing the first bracket. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you think this would add `(`?

Comment: Hi Mark, with the overlay I was only able to add a ')' at the end .but could not go lower than 1 to add at beginning.  The answer I received done it for me. THank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
update table set column='('||column||')' where table_ID=1
```